# creating variables using multi-dimensional in SAS 9.4

Tags: multidimensional-array, sas

I have a toy dataset:

```
 data step1;
     input var1 - var16;
     datalines;
     25000 26000 27000 28000 29000 30000 31000 32000 0.45 0.25 0.35 0.60 0.75 0.29 0.45 0.51
    ;
    run;
```

i'm trying to create new variables. One way is to do it individually i.e

```
var17 = var1 - D*var9;
var18 = var1 - D*var10;
var19 = var2 - D*var11;
..
..
```

But it is time intensive and prone to mistake. I want to use multi-dimensional array. I ran the following code.

The code to create new variable is:

```
 data step2;
 set step1;
 array A{2,2,2} var9-var16;
 array C{2,2,2,4} var17 - var48;
 array B{2,4} var1-var8;

 D = 250;
 do f = 1 to 4;
   do i = 1 to 2;
      do j = 1 to 2;
         do m = 1 to 2;
            C{i,j,m,f} = B{j,f} - D*A{i,j,m};
            output;
         end;
      end;
    end;
 end;
stop;
run;
```

The code this time runs but gives me 32 rows.But i want the new variables created in one row only. What is wrong then? Is there any other way to achieve my objective? I'm using SAS 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current framing of the question, you need to remove the STOP statement and the OUTPUT statement.

> The STOP statement causes SAS to stop processing the current DATA step immediately and resume processing statements after the end of the current DATA step.

```
     data step1;
     input var1 - var16;
     datalines;
     25000 26000 27000 28000 29000 30000 31000 32000 0.45 0.25 0.35 0.60 0.75 0.29 0.45 0.51
    ;
    run;

 data step2;
 set step1;
 array A{2,2,2} var9-var16;
 array C{2,2,2,4} var17 - var48;
 array B{2,4} var1-var8;

 D = 250;
 do f = 1 to 4;
   do i = 1 to 2;
      do j = 1 to 2;
         do m = 1 to 2;
            C{i,j,m,f} = B{j,f} - D*A{i,j,m};
         end;
      end;
    end;
 end;

run;
```

Comment: @ Reeza: please let me know if that clears it. I made changes related to the sequence of {i,j,m} in DO loop.Also i made the changes you suggested. But that is creating another issue